# Random passcode generator in python error

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I am attempting a random passcode generator, however we may only use certain special symbols, which I listed, but the code keeps non running into an error that I am unsure how to go about solving; `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`         .

This is the part of code that I am working on.

```
while True:
    import string

    a  = ["!", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+"]
    from random import *
    characters = string.ascii_letters + a + string.digits
    passcode =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(8, 12)))
    print (passcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `a` to be a `str`:

```py
import string
import random


a  = "!$%^&*()-_=+"
characters = string.ascii_letters + a + string.digits
passcode =  "".join(random.choice(characters) for x in range(random.randint(8, 12)))
print(passcode)
```

Also, it is bad practice to import the entire `random` namespace using `from random import *`.
When your code is working, you should post on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some tips and improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating  your list to your string. You need to make the following changes and it should work.

```
a  = "!$%^&*()-_=+"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a string using list `a`, `"".join(a)`. and it will be better if you declare your list `a` outside the loop.

```
import string
import random
a  = ["!", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+"]

while True:

    characters = string.ascii_letters + "".join(a)  + string.digits

    passcode =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(8, 12)))
    print (passcode)
```

Comment: This is a bad example. You are eclipsing a builtin function by using `str` as a variable and polluting your program's namespace by using `import *`.

Comment: @Alex, solved it. Currently, I'm working on C# project. MIxed it up. My bad :(

Comment: @Alex, I did some research about `import *` thanks to you. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Check types:

```
import string
a  = ["!", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+"]
print(type(string.ascii_letters))  # <class 'str'>
print(type(a))  # <class 'list'>
print(type(string.digits))  # <class 'str'>
```

You need to either convert all `list`s to `str` or all `str`s to `list` before concatenation that is you should do:

```
characters = string.ascii_letters + "".join(a) + string.digits
```

or

```
characters = list(string.ascii_letters) + a + list(string.digits)
```

in first case you get `characters` as `str`, in second as `list` - both are accepted by `random.choice`. As side note: do not `import` inside loop, it is enough to `import` once.